# Replay a chapter in Magicka?

Tags: magicka

Can you replay a chapter in Magicka without losing your current place?
If so, how?

<sub>I really want to get that magick I missed...</sub>

Comment: Hey, @cross Move your checkmark so I can delete my out of date answer!

Answer (score 15):

Since the [update 1.4.3.1](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2235109), an option allows the player to revisit old chapters in a campaign. You just have to click on the name of the chapter on the select screen.

> Changelog for Magicka Patch 1.4.3.1 2011-11-15
>
> • Added saveable checkpoints. Checkpoints will now save your progress
>   up to that point.
>
> • Added a automatic-revive fairy for single player games.
>
> • **Added an option to revisit old chapters in a campaign.**
>
> • Improved server browser usability.
>
> • Improved body collision detection and overall physics.

Answer (score 4):

You can restart any chapter you have to point on map and load chapter you want.